# Grammar about listening to something

Tags: grammar

This is the sentence that I am confused.

I enjoy listening to **others sing**.

As far as I know "listening to" should be followed by a Noun.
What is the function of the word "others" and "sing"?

Is this correct?

others is functioned as a *Subject*

sing is functioned as a *Verb*

or

others sing is functioned as *Noun*

Comment: "Others sing" is a clause functioning as object of the preposition "to". The clause has "others" as subject and "sing" as the predicate verb phrase. The whole preposition phrase "to others sing" is then complement of "listen".

Comment: Think of it as "I enjoy listening to *other people* sing."